# Get Dynamiclly loaded Source Code from python using mechanize and bs4

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, mechanize

I want to get source code of page that loads from javascript actually that page is linkedin profile page and i want to get job and education details.

**I'm not using selenium i don't want browser window to open i know about headless but cookies problem**

I have logedin through mechanize and i have get some data like phone number, address, headlines, emails, and Full Name. But as it is loaded from javascript so i can't get whole page data.

Data getting:

```
.....<code id="bpr-guid-892585" style="display: none">
  {"data":{"entityUrn":"urn:li:collectionResponse:uPYuDSPXzooiHx+zPOguG1+f+JFMWTWFEfhiIQtEFMM=","elements":[],"paging":{"count":10,"start":0,"total":0,"links":[]},"$type":"com.linkedin.restli.common.CollectionResponse"},"included":[]}
</code>
<code id="datalet-bpr-guid-892585" style="display: none">
  {"request":"/voyager/api/takeovers","status":200,"body":"bpr-guid-892585","method":"GET","headers":{"x-li-uuid":"AAXafRyXk/WxvhRuOZTrnA\u003D\u003D"}}
</code>
<img class="datalet-bpr-guid-892585" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" style="display: none"/><code id="bpr-guid-892586" style="display: none">
  {"data":{"entityUrn":"urn:li:collectionResponse:nZx6/1e1AAbOHh075gv083zrunZT186/K+rx5FP70A4=","elements":[{"lixTracking":{"urn":"urn:li:member:865882626","segmentIndex":2,"experimentId":4358724,"treatmentIndex":1,"$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.common.ChameleonConfigLixTrackingInfo"},"data":{"namespace":"premium/templates/components/chooser/plan-card","locale":"en_US","message":"Learn more","key":"i18n_card_select_plan","$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.common.ChameleonConfigDataI18n"},"displayName":"card_select_plan","description":"testing 'Learn more' on SKU cards, vs control of 'Select plan' ","lixTreatment":"VAR_t20152_PR_1","lixKey":"chameleon.PREMIUM:us.copy.17654","creatorDisplayName":"cyount","status":"PERMANENT_RAMP","$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.common.ChameleonConfigItem"},{"lixTracking":{"urn":"urn:li:member:865882626","segmentIndex":3,"experimentId":4395729,"treatmentIndex":0,"$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.common.ChameleonConfigLixTrackingInfo"},"data":{"namespace":"onboarding/templates/components/widgets/people-you-may-know","locale":"en_US","message":"Connecting with people lets you see updates and keep in touch","key":"i18n_onboarding_pymk_page_header_phase_3","$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.common.ChameleonConfigDataI18n"},"displayName":"onboarding_pymk_page_header_phase_3","description":"Onboarding PEOPLE_YOU_MAY_KNOW widget header copy test","lixTreatment":"control","lixKey":"chameleon.ONBOARDING:global.copy.19060","creatorDisplayName":"zihliu","status":"MAX_RAMP","$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.common.ChameleonConfigItem"},{"lixTracking":{"urn":"urn:li:member:865882626","segmentIndex":3,"experimentId":4395707,"treatmentIndex":1,"$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.common.ChameleonConfigLixTrackingInfo"},"data":{"namespace":"onboarding/templates/components/widgets/profile-edit-common","locale":"en_US","message":"What’s your most recent experience?","key":"i18n_onboarding_profile_edit_work_header_v2","$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.common.ChameleonConfigDataI18n"},"displayName":"onboarding_profile_edit_work_header_v2","description":"Onboarding PROFILE_EDIT widget header copy test","lixTreatment":"VAR_t21697_PR_1","lixKey":"chameleon.ONBOARDING:global.copy.19063","$recipeTypes":["com.linkedin.voyager.dash.deco.relationships.ProfileWithEmailRequired","com.linkedin.voyager.dash.deco.identity.profile.WebTopCardCore"],"$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.dash.identity.profile.Profile","firstName":"Adarsh ","profilePicture":{"displayImageWithFrameReferenceUnion":{"vectorImage":{"$recipeTypes":["com.linkedin.voyager.dash.deco.common.VectorImageOnlyRootUrlAndAttribution"],"rootUrl":"https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E35AQEIVkoUWgLFvw/profile-framedphoto-shrink_","artifacts":[{"width":200,"$recipeTypes":["com.linkedin.voyager.dash.deco.common.VectorArtifact"],"fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment":"200_200/0/1597096649541?e=1647694800&amp;v=beta&amp;t=XVOK0upwO6V3NaJtUWLwy-yLMDa8cZICzYH0do67vhU","expiresAt":1647694800000,"height":200,"$type":"com.linkedin.common.VectorArtifact"},{"width":400,"$recipeTypes":["com.linkedin.voyager.dash.deco.common.VectorArtifact"],"fileIdentif
</code>
<img class="terminatorlet" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" style="display: none"/>
<div aria-live="polite" class="visually-hidden" id="a11y-notification" role="region"></div>
</body></html>
```

And also if there is way by using of selenium then please guide me but using headless attribute.

It contains all data that i mentiond above but when loaded from browser after login it's different.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: first try to do it without `headless` attribute - to see if it works, and later use `headless`

Comment: if page uises JavaScript to load data from other URL then you may try to use (manually)  `DevTools` in `Chrome`/`Firefox` (tab: `Network`) to find this URL - so  later you can use this URL in code to get data.

Comment: It will does the work but for access profile page I need to login else it will ask for verification which can't without human and I have used devtool and on network tab it fetch url but every it will different for different profile.

Comment: with `selenium` you can try to use profile (which was used to login) and it should access page without login. With other tools you may need first GET page with login form (to get cookies and unique/hidden values in form) , and next send POST with login/password (cookies and unique/hidden values from form) to access pages. It can work if page doesn't use JavaScript to generate some unique value.